# SQL Multiple Calculation in Same & Next Row

Tags: sql-server, loops, multiple-columns, recursive-query, calculation

I have use case to do multiple steps of calculation in SQL Server.
Basically, I need to fetch the result from previous calculation, re-calculate in current row, then send the value to the next row.
I already try to use While Loop & Recursive CTE, but seems it have very slow performance, since I have 700K++ data that need being calculate in single process.

Here's the sample input data:

**Input Table**

| ITEM | MONTH | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 202308 | 10 | 8 | 20 | 0 |
| XYZ | 202309 | 4 | 4 |  |  |
| XYZ | 202310 | 15 | 7 |  |  |
| XYZ | 202311 | 8 | 11 |  |  |

**Output Table**

| ITEM | MONTH | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 202308 | 10 | 8 | 20 | 0 |
| XYZ | 202309 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 0 |
| XYZ | 202310 | 15 | 7 | 6 | 16 |
| XYZ | 202311 | 8 | 11 | 7 | 12 |

**Formula**

1. For first record, we always get the **A**,**B**, and **C** value. For **D** in first record, we can calulate it by using formula:

- CASE
  WHEN A+B-C < 0 THEN 0
  ELSE A+B-C
  END

2. For the next record, we only have the **A** and **B** data.

- To calculate **C** in next row, we must use formula:
  **C09 = C08 + A08 - D08(After Case when)**
- To calculate **D** in next row, we muse use formula:
  **D09 = A09 + B09 -C09(from above formula)**

Is there any simple way or windows function that I can use in SQL Server to solve this complex calculation?

Since, if I try to use Recursive/Loop there'll be performance issue in the calculation process.

Appreciate if you guys have suggestions for me to solve this complex calculation use case!

Comment: Please don't use images, use tabular text

Comment: do you have index on date, otherwise you will indeed have bad performance if you advance

Comment: Some sample data and expected result would help to make things much more clear, and not in an image but in text form that we can copy/paste into test data

Comment: I already add the tabular table for sample data input & sample data output, thanks for the reminder!